# In Jsoup , Why getElementById() returning null object and the given HTML string printing with twice with syntax error when .outerHTML() called?

Tags: javascript, java, html, dom, jsoup

I am developing an application using Java which reads html tags. I am using JSOUP library to read HTML tags

**My Problem**
 I created an `Element` tag by giving a html content as string ..

The html tag;

```
<li id="comment_layout">
         <div class="img"><img src="http://www.prankmenot.com/assets/images/facebook/profile.jpg" width="32" height="32"></div>
         <div class="txt">
            <strong><a href="#" id="post_commenter">Sathish Kumar</a></strong> 
            <p id="post_comment" >Yes. Let develop this. </p>
            <div class="txtbottom"><a href="#" class="text-liketext">Like</a> · <a href="#">Reply</a> ·  <img src="http://www.prankmenot.com/assets/images/facebook/facebook_like_thumb.png"> <a href="#">5</a>  · <span style="color:#9197a3;">5 mins</span>
         </div>
         </div><div class="clearfix"></div>                            
      </li>
```

The HTML string object

```
 public static final String CommentLi = "<li id=\"comment_layout\">" +
            " <div class=\"img\"><img src=\"http://www.prankmenot.com/assets/images/facebook/profile.jpg\" width=\"32\" height=\"32\"></div>" +
            " <div class=\"txt\"> <strong><a href=\"#\" id=\"post_commenter\">Sathish Kumar</a></strong> " +
            "<p id=\"post_comment\" >Yes. Let develop this. </p>" +
            " <div class=\"txtbottom\">" +
            "<a href=\"#\" class=\"text-liketext\">Like</a> · <a href=\"#\">Reply</a>" +
            " · <img src=\"http://www.prankmenot.com/assets/images/facebook/facebook_like_thumb.png\">" +
            " <a href=\"#\">5</a> · <span style=\"color:#9197a3;\">5 mins</span>" +
            " </div> " +
            "</div>" +
            "<div class=\"clearfix\">" +
            "</div>" +
            " </li>";
```

Now I created the `Element` Object:

```
        Element commmentLayout = new Element(TagStore.CommentLi);
        String commentLAyoutHTML = commmentLayout.outerHtml();
        System.out.println("The comments layout==>   "+commentLAyoutHTML);

        Element commentContent=commmentLayout.getElementById("post_comment");
        String commenContentHTML = commentContent.outerHtml();
        System.out.println(commenContentHTML);
```

> Now my problem is , when I execute the `commentContent.outerHtml()` , it
>   produces null pointer execption since `commentContent` is null because
>   `commmentLayout.getElementById("post_comment")` method invocation
>   returns `null` object.

I examined the html content. It having the "`post_comment`" id tag. (  `<p id="post_comment" >Yes. Let develop this. </p>`).

But I cant figure out why `getElementById` returning null even html contains the tag with that ID.

In order test the input , I printed the commmentLayout object. The output is weired.

```
The comments layout ==>  <<li id="comment_layout"> <div class="img"><img src="http://www.prankmenot.com/assets/images/facebook/profile.jpg" width="32" height="32"></div> <div class="txt"> <strong><a href="#" id="post_commenter">Sathish Kumar</a></strong> <p id="post_comment" >Yes. Let develop this. </p> <div class="txtbottom"><a href="#" class="text-liketext">Like</a> · <a href="#">Reply</a> · <img src="http://www.prankmenot.com/assets/images/facebook/facebook_like_thumb.png"> <a href="#">5</a> · <span style="color:#9197a3;">5 mins</span> </div> </div><div class="clearfix"></div> </li>></<li id="comment_layout"> <div class="img"><img src="http://www.prankmenot.com/assets/images/facebook/profile.jpg" width="32" height="32"></div> <div class="txt"> <strong><a href="#" id="post_commenter">Sathish Kumar</a></strong> <p id="post_comment" >Yes. Let develop this. </p> <div class="txtbottom"><a href="#" class="text-liketext">Like</a> · <a href="#">Reply</a> · <img src="http://www.prankmenot.com/assets/images/facebook/facebook_like_thumb.png"> <a href="#">5</a> · <span style="color:#9197a3;">5 mins</span> </div> </div><div class="clearfix"></div> </li>>
```

Examine the above console output.. The html tag starts with `<<li ...` instead of `<li ...` . And the same html repeated twice in the output. (Note that the `<li id = "comment_layout">` repeating twice in the output. Also the joining place of repeated html having wrong syntax   `</li>></<li` )

I can't figure out the issue. My questions are :

- Why this issue occurring. ?
- Why I can't get elementbyid() ?
- Why theElement object returing input html two times with syntax errors ?